# C# class default method

Tags: c#, class, function, methods, default

Is there a way to assign a default method to a class like this:

```
public class EscMenu
{
    public static void EscMenu()
    {
        //do something
    }

   public static void SomeOtherMethod()
   {
       //do something else
   }
}
```

So when I call  `EscMenu.SomeOtherMethod();` in another class in the same solution, it does "do something else", but I cannot call `EscMenu();`.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay, Im gonna try to explain this in a better way:

I just want the class `EscMenu` to do something when I call it from another (external) class like this: `EscMenu();`. Of course I could easily create a method `default()` in `EscMenu` and call `EscMenu.default();` externally. But I would really like to just call `EscMenu();`

If that just isn't possible or I continue to fail in explaining myself, then just don't mind ;-)

Thanks again!

Comment: Hard to understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by "**I cannot call "EscMenu();"**" ?

Comment: Edited my question. Hope I explained myself better this time ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't give a method the same name as its containing type - and you really don't want to confuse the name of a type with the name of a method anyway. Why introduce the ambiguity?

If you could give some example where you want to write code in some way other than what's already available, we may be able to help you more. (For example, it *may* be that extension methods could help.)

Comment: @janw: Okay, basically no, you can't do this. Frankly I'm glad - because it would *look* like your code was doing one thing (trying to find a method called `EscMenu` in the current scope) when it was actually trying to do another.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "default" method is a kind of absurdity in C#, but from what I can glean from your requirements, you don't want to be able to call `EscMenu` externally (i.e outside of the class), so for that use the `private` access modifier:

```
private static void EscMenu(){
    //do something
}
```

But you would need a distinct name for the member.

Answer (score 0):

I don't knwo what you mean with default method. But to prevent other classes to call methods in your class ExcMenu, you can make your method private:

```
public class EscMenu
{
    private static void EscMenu()
    {
       //do something
    }

    public static void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there (if you cleaned up the syntax) is a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> - A static constructor does not take access modifiers or have parameters.
> - A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.
> - **A static constructor cannot be called directly.**
> - The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.

Comment: It's not a static constructor because return type, or even `void` is illegal in this case - it's more fitting to say that what they have is a method, but with an illegal name.

Comment: True. What they have there could be interpreted as an improper attempt to be a static constructor, or an improper attempt to be a member function. I've clarified in the original answer.